# Virtualbox ubuntu VM gets no IP on a wired connection, gets it on Wifi

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Windows 10 Enterprise host running Oracle VirtualBox. I have 3 ubuntu (1604) VMs installed on them. They are all configured as a bridge network. When I use a wired LAN connection none of the VMs connect to the network, they never get an IP. But if I use a wifi (say a mobile wifi) all of the get IPs and things work great.

Any pointers to how to solve this and always get IPs on wired network would be of great help. Thanks

EDIT:
It is  bridged on both wired and wireless. The issue is more on the office network, the LAN port had to be enabled for some 802.11 setting (I dont understand this), and I am told that this has been done by the network folks.  I have seen that I don't get IP on wired even at home sometimes but do get it at other times, its not consistent. Any wireless always seems to work.

Comment: Are they bridged to the wireless network interface only? You may have to create another bridge for the wired interface. Is this a home network or in an office? I ask this wondering if the wired network requires a certificate.

Comment: Windows XP? What version of VirtualBox do you use?

Comment: @xenoid, The OS is Windows 10 Enterprise, not XP. Corrected above now. VB is 6.0.

Comment: @Gordster, They are bridged on both wired and wireless. The issue is more on the office network, the LAN port had to be enabled for some 802.11 setting (I dont understand this), and I am told that this has been done. In my post I did not mention office or home I have seen that I dont get IP on wired even at home sometimes, maybe I should have mentioned this. I have edited above now

Comment: Does networking work if you assign an IP address manually? Is there a DHCP server available on LAN? Have you ran `dhclient` on the VMs? How were you able to bridge two network devices to one virtual network adapter?